# Bubble sort выдает ошибку

Tags: java

```
package com.company;

public class BubbleSort {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        float[] array = new float[] {18, 2, 21, 3, 9};
        float swap;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            if(array[i] > array[i + 1]){
                swap = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i + 1];
                array[i + 1] = swap;
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
            System.out.print(array[x] + " ");
        System.out.print("");
    }
}
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 5

В чем проблема?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` => `for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

В комментариях уже дали ответ, но я немного уточню здесь.
В цикле, обрабатывающем массив лучше указывать не конкретное значение в условии выполнения, а привязываться к длине массива: `for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)`. В вашем случае, в первом цикле перебор должен заканчиваться на предпоследнем элементе. Следовательно, описание цикла должно выглядеть так: `for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)`
В таком виде, даже если вы добавите в массив новые элементы, или удалите из него какие-то уже существующие, ошибки не возникнет, так как условие выполнения всегда будет корректным.

Это к вопросу не относится, но данный код не отсортирует этот массив. В ответе вы получите `{ 2.0 18.0 3.0 9.0 21.0 }`.  Для пузырьковой сортировки недостаточно переставить некоторые элементы массива между собой. Алгоритм должен быть немного сложнее. И еще, посмотрите, может быть вам стоит поменять тип массива с `float` на `int`, раз уж вы используете в массиве целочисленные значения...